# Insert JSON file in specific tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my JSON that i try to load to mysql

```
{
    "business_id": "fNGIbpazjTRdXgwRY_NIXA",
    "full_address": "1201 Washington Ave\nCarnegie, PA 15106",
    "hours": {

    },
    "open": true,
    "categories": ["Bars",
                   "American (Traditional)",
                   "Nightlife",
                   "Lounges",
                   "Restaurants"],
    "city": "Carnegie",
    "review_count": 5,
    "name": "Rocky's Lounge",
    "neighborhoods": [],
    "longitude": -80.084941599999993,
    "state": "PA",
    "stars": 4.0,
    "latitude": 40.396468800000001,
    "attributes": {
        "Alcohol": "full_bar",
        "Noise Level": "average",
        "Music": {
            "dj": false,
            "background_music": true,
            "karaoke": false,
            "live": false,
            "video": false,
            "jukebox": false
        },
        "Attire": "casual",
        "Ambience": {
            "romantic": false,
            "intimate": false,
            "touristy": false,
            "hipster": false,
            "divey": false,
            "classy": false,
            "trendy": false,
            "upscale": false,
            "casual": false
        },
        "Good for Kids": true,
        "Wheelchair Accessible": false,
        "Good For Dancing": false,
        "Delivery": false,
        "Coat Check": false,
        "Smoking": "no",
        "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
        "Take-out": false,
        "Price Range": 2,
        "Outdoor Seating": false,
        "Takes Reservations": false,
        "Waiter Service": true,
        "Caters": false,
        "Good For": {
            "dessert": false,
            "latenight": false,
            "lunch": false,
            "dinner": false,
            "brunch": false,
            "breakfast": false
        },
        "Parking": {
            "garage": false,
            "street": false,
            "validated": false,
            "lot": false,
            "valet": false
        },
        "Has TV": true,
        "Good For Groups": true
    },
    "type": "business"
}
```

And im using the following code

```
<?php
   try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:118;dbname=mydb", "root", "1234");
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    //read the json file contents
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('c:\yelp_academic_dataset_business.json');

    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    //get the employee details
    $idBusiness = $data['business_id'];
    $name = $data['name'];
    $neighborhoods = $data['neighborhoods'];
    $full_address = $data['full_address'];
    $city = $data['city'];
    $state = $data['state'];
    $latitude = $data['latitude'];
    $longitude = $data['longitude'];
    $stars = $data['stars'];
    $review_count = $data['review_count'];
    $open = $data['open'];
 $procedure = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO business(business_id, name, neighborhoods, full_address, city, state, latitude, longitude, stars, review_count, open)
    VALUES('$idBusiness', '$name', '$neighborhoods', '$full_address', '$city', '$state', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$stars', '$review_count', '$open')");
   $procedure -> execute(); ?>
```

The script run but not is inserted in database, don t know what happen.

Then i have another question.

For example to attributes i can t load that way to mysql so i need to create 2 tables that i named "Atributos complexos" that are the ones that have a lot of attributes inside like Music and Ambience, and "Atributos Simples" such as alcohol, noise level. In "atributos simples" i create 2 fiels, Designation and value, which translates to the alcohol be the designation and full bar the value.
My doubt is how i parse the data so the alcohol and this "atributos simples" can be loaded to the field Designation in the table "Atributos Simples" in mysql.

Can anyone help me please, its really important

Comment: You're using PDO prepared statements, which is great, but don't forget to use [placeholder values](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of using string interpolation. This code is full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) since nothing is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can help. Firstly I would change your current code to the following:

```
<?php
//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$procedure = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO business (business_id, name, neighborhoods, full_address, city, state, latitude, longitude, stars, review_count, open)
VALUES (:business_id, :name, :neighborhoods, :full_address, :city, :state, :latitude, :longitude, :stars, :review_count, :open)");

$procedure->bindParam(':business_id', $data['business_id']);
$procedure->bindParam(':name', $data['name']);
$procedure->bindParam(':neighborhoods', $data['neighborhoods']);
$procedure->bindParam(':full_address', $data['full_address']);
$procedure->bindParam(':city', $data['city']);
$procedure->bindParam(':state', $data['state']);
$procedure->bindParam(':latitude', $data['latitude']);
$procedure->bindParam(':longitude', $data['longitude']);
$procedure->bindParam(':stars', $data['stars']);
$procedure->bindParam(':review_count', $data['review_count']);
$procedure->bindParam(':open', $data['open']);

$procedure->execute() or die(print_r($procedure->errorInfo(), true));
?>
```

The `die` statement should give you some information of why the insert failed.

Regarding your second question, you need a minimum of three fields: `business_id`, `designation`, `value`. You need `business_id` in order to link later on to the information.

Personally to populate the `atributos_simples` table I would do the following:

```
foreach($data['attributes'] as $k=>$v)
{
     if(!is_array($v))
     {
            $simple = null;

            $simple = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO atributos_simples (business_id,designation,value) VALUES (:business_id,:designation,:value)");

            $simple->bindParam(':business_id', $data['business_id']);
            $simple->bindParam(':designation', $k);
            $simple->bindParam(':value', $v);

            $simple->execute();
      }
}
```

This should get you there or there about where you would like to be.